# Is it possible to generate a pdf version 1.7 using puppeteer or headless Chrome?

Tags: pdf, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Testing I have seen that Chrome when printing an html ('save as pdf') generates a version 1.7 pdf. However, doing tests with puppeteer and chrome headless, I see that the pdf file I get is version 1.4. If I'm not mistaken, I have seen that they both use Blink as their rendering engine.

So why the difference in pdf versions? Is there an option to get a pdf version of 1.7 through puppeteer?

Comment: A PDF should have the lowest version number it is compatible with. If you require no specific things that would require a version higher than 1.4, then 1.4 is correct and using 1.7 is wrong.

Comment: The thing is that I need to generate accesible pdfs and I think that 1.4 has some restrictions with marks.

Answer (score 0):

You mention your concern that you think you need not less than 1.7 for PDF accessibility Features.

If you read this years (1/27/21) "PDF Accessibility API Reference" it clearly does not mention 1.7 but does mention 1.4 as the level Tagging was introduced.

"Tagged PDF, introduced in PDF 1.4, defines a logical structure for the document that corresponds to the logical order of the content, regardless of the order in which the content is rendered."

That is not to say later enhancements are not useful but 1.4 is the minimum for Tagging.

https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_access.pdf

To a large extent the value is meaningless as most readers accept 1.0 to 2.0 but may warn that not all higher version features are supported. Equally not all 1.4 compatible readers support Accessibility Tagging.

Where it is defined more emphatically is in PDF/A where

PDF/A-1 uses 1.4 as the target level and

PDF/A-2 uses 1.7 as the target level and

PDF/A-4 uses 2.0 as the target level